# How many certifications are realistically possible to achieve just by trailhead?

Tags: trailhead, certification

I have just started learning salesforce. I don't have any IT experience as I have just finished engineering. Online courses are really expensive so I want rely only on trailhead. I've just started the 'admin beginner trail' so that I can give the exam for admin certification in the near future. Is this enough or do I need additional trails / non-trailhead resources to practise? I also want to know how many salesforce certifications can be achieved just by relying on trailhead and nothing else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are even architect trail mixes available, not sure what you mean

Comment: Anecdotally, I started with no hands on SF experience and taught myself enough to work as a full time developer without using trailhead or attending training classes. Mostly used this stack & documentation. Granted I have a background in computer science but its very possible to train yourself to fit their skillsets & pass certifications.

Answer (score 1):

Every Salesforce certification has an Exam Guide linked on its Trailhead page (see [Administrator](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/administrator) for example). The Exam Guide lays out what material you are expected to know to pass the exam successfully.

It's up to you to ensure you have mastered that material. The Trailmixes linked on each exam page are a good start. You will almost certainly also spend a good deal of time with the Salesforce documentation, and possibly other resources too, to ensure you have the mastery of the material on the Exam Guide required to pass. It is *up to you* and how you learn. Nobody can tell you exactly what you, as a unique learner, will need to master that area.